# What is the average length of a Python module

Tags: python, package, python-module

I have bits and bobs of code and I'm thinking of getting them in a python module. But I might need a Python package.
I know it has to do mostly with how I want to divide my code.
But I still need to know what is an average length (in lines) of a python module.

Using the following numbers please select   small | average | big

- 1,000 lines of python
- 10,000 lines
- 50,000 lines
- 100,000 lines
- 1,000,000 lines

Please help.

Comment: Lines of code are irrelevant. Split by semantic connection.

Comment: @timgeb thanks. So if I have a module with 10 lines (one function) that's fine? what about a module with 1M lines (5000 function)?

Comment: A module with a single function is fine if that function has little semantic connection to other modules. If it nicely fits into another module, put it there instead. In a module with 5000 functions you will with no doubt find groups of related functions that either help each other, perform similar or connected tasks. These should go into their own modules then. There's no hard rules when to split a module into two or more. You'll have to use common sense.

Comment: This seems like a homework question.  is it? if so you should remove the question.

Comment: @lhasadad what is a homework question?

Comment: @lhasadad Homework questions do not need to be removed, but they need to be clearly marked as homework, and they still need to follow the guidelines for[ what makes a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Thedude Look at the modules in the standard library, and figure out what their average length is. That should give you a feel for how large a module is in practice. However, the number doesn't mean anything. Nothing in the language cares how big or small a module is; only experience with writing modules will tell you when a group of small modules should be combined into one larger one, or when a large module should be split into separate smaller modules.

Comment: "The dude":   homework questions refer to questions that are the result of someones programming homework.  as @clepner pointed out the do not need to be removed, but they should provide value to the community.  basically we are happy to help answer questions, just don't want folks to get the idea they will get the answers to their quiz questions etc by dumping them here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A module should be the smallest indepently useable unit of code. That's what modules are for: modularity, independence, take only what you need. A package should be a set of modules that functionally belong together to cover a certain problem area, e.g. statistical computations or 3D graphics.

So the number of lines is not really important. Still I think modules of 10000+ lines are rare. But there's no lower bound.

Comment: "A module should be the smallest indepently useable unit of code." I think you are making this sound way too easy. Define "smallest possible". Should every module level helper function have its own module?

Comment: @timeb Sorry if it sounds easy. Coupling, cohesion and thin interfaces are at the core of the art of designing good software. It isn't easy at all, very hard to pin down and a matter of experience. On this subject I'm still learning every day. But, even if it isn't easy, looking at these aspects is necessary, counting lines of code won't help much.